# Using HTTPUrlConnection for REST API call to Parse server

Tags: android, rest, curl, parse-platform

I'm trying to make a RESTful API call to a Parse.com server using HTTPURLConnection. Unfortunately, when I run the code below, I get an error of HTTP 401 (Unauthorised Access)

Here are the codes

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
try {
  URL url = new URL("https://api.parse.com/1/functions/hello");
  urlConnection =
    (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

  urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
  urlConnection.setReadTimeout(20000);
  urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
  urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
  urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-Application-Id", appId);
  urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", restApiKey);
  urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
  urlConnection.connect();

  byte[] outputBytes = "{}".getBytes("UTF-8");
  OutputStream out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
  out.write(outputBytes);
  out.close();

  int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
  if (statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_ACCEPTED) {
    Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground(): connection failed: statusCode: " + statusCode);
    //                    return null;
  }

  InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
      urlConnection.getInputStream());
  String responseText = getResponseText(in);
  Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground() responseText: " + responseText);
  return new JSONObject(responseText);

} catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (urlConnection != null) {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
  }
}
return null;
```

Basically, all I need is to replicate the functionality of this cURL:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: {APP_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: {API_KEY}" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/functions/hello
```

I ran the exact same cURL command with the same App ID and API key, and they are returning the correct result.

Any suggestions ??

EDIT:

Here is the console output I get:

```
09-24 14:28:43.101  21868-22057/com.example.versiontrack D/Module_VersionTracker﹕ doInBackground(): connection failed: statusCode: 401
09-24 14:28:43.102  21868-22057/com.example.versiontrack W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.parse.com/1/functions/hello
09-24 14:28:43.102  21868-22057/com.example.versiontrack W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
09-24 14:28:43.103  21868-22057/com.example.versiontrack W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
09-24 14:28:43.103  21868-22057/com.example.versiontrack W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
09-24 14:28:43.104  21868-22057/com.example.versiontrack W/System.err﹕ at com.example.module_versiontracker.Module_VersionTracker$ParseVersionCheckTask.doInBackground(Module_VersionTracker.java:215)
09-24 14:28:43.104  21868-22057/com.example.versiontrack W/System.err﹕ at com.example.module_versiontracker.Module_VersionTracker$ParseVersionCheckTask.doInBackground(Module_VersionTracker.java:115)
09-24 14:28:43.104  21868-22057/com.example.versiontrack W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-24 14:28:43.104  21868-22057/com.example.versiontrack W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-24 14:28:43.104  21868-22057/com.example.versiontrack W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-24 14:28:43.104  21868-22057/com.example.versiontrack W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-24 14:28:43.104  21868-22057/com.example.versiontrack W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-24 14:28:43.105  21868-22057/com.example.versiontrack W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: HttpURLConnection.HTTP_ACCEPTED = 202, don't you want to look to 200 (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) ? Btw your code seems good. 401 can only comes from the server. Check `String urlReturned = httpsURLConnection.getURL().toString();` to see if the url is not modified.

Comment: The URL is the same.

Comment: So you can see the outputs of the request property with: `Map<String, List<String>> map = httpURLConnection.getRequestProperties();
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "entry:" + entry.getKey());
            for (String str : entry.getValue()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "value:" + str);
            }
        }` and see if your authentication is correct.

Comment: So I got the same problem, have you got it working???

Comment: I did. The code was working fine.
The issue was that I mistakingly copy-pasted the API_KEY instead of the  REST_API key from Parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to flush the output stream.

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
out.write(outputBytes);
out.flush(); //Don't forgot to flush the output
out.close();
```

Comment: No difference at all. Please check my edit for a console output.